# There was a problem when I convert .pdf to .ps via gs

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, postscript

I Have a PDF file, I want to convert it to a PS file, then I execute below command

```
# file d00137-001
/var/spool/cups/d00137-001: PDF document, version 1.4
# gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=ps2write -sOutputFile=d00130 d00137-001
```

and then, I see a lot of error output:

```
**** Error: File has an unbalanced >> (close dictionary).
            Output may be incorrect.
**** Error: obj definition followed by multiple tokens, attempting to recover.
           Output may be incorrect.
**** Error: obj definition followed by multiple tokens, attempting to recover.

......    /* Skip 11 lines of the same output */

**** Error: Tf refers to a resource key with an invalid value type: marktype. Assuming resource key: F7 is a font name.
           Output may be incorrect.
**** Error: Tf refers to a resource key with an invalid value type: marktype. Assuming resource key: F7 is a font name.
           Output may be incorrect.
......    /* Skip 11 lines of the same output */

# file d00130
/var/spool/cups/d00130: PostScript document text conforming DSC level 3.0, Level 2
# ls -l d00130 d00137-001 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 203745 3月  15 14:27 d00130
-rw-r----- 1 root lp     6565 3月  15 14:27 d00137-001
```

But I see d00130 is a blank document when I view it via evince or printing it via a HP printer. Is there a problem with the PDF file format, or do I need to adjust my command parameters? but the original PDF file can be opened for viewing or printing.

Thanks very much.

If you need the original PDF file, you can leave your email and I will send it to you.

Thanks again.

Comment: I'd have thought the long sequence of error messages tells its own tale. Ghostscript thinks your PDF file is broken. Every time it comes across a content stream which is broken it skips that stream. This can lead to the entire document being elided. You haven't said which version of Ghostscript you are using (current version is 9.26), and its impossible to tell whether the PDF file is valid without seeing it. No, I'm not going to post my email address in a public site for spammers to scrape. If you post the file somewhere then I'll look at it for you.

Comment: I think what you said makes sense, can you access this link?
: https://pan.baidu.com/s/1j1DoLz0p4o6MiG2ohNMENA 
fetch code: 2mv6

Comment: The main problem is that I can't control the generation of this file, so I'm trying to find a way to work with it.

Comment: Wish you have a nice day ☺

Comment: I can reach the URL but I'm afraid my pitiful Chinese isn't up to the job of reading what the dialog says and Chrome doesn't even offer to translate it :-( Pressing the button changes some of the text and turns it red, so I guess I'm doing somethign wrong. Presumably it wants a password. What version of GS are you using ? It may be that this is somethign which has already been worked around/fixed.

Comment: I think this issue is gs did not found the chinese font my used. this font path is /usr/share/fonts/truetype/yozo/yzdwkj6.ttf, I have try to add this font to /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Init/cidfmap, but the PDF file have below line: /BaseFont /Yozo Kai. how can I do for this description information is a two-word font? If I use below script to describe this font, printing driver will output filter failed log.
 /Yozo Kai << /FileType /TrueType
  /Path pssystemparams /GenericResourceDir get
  (/usr/share/fonts/truetype/yozo/yzdwkj6.ttf) concatstrings
  /CSI [(GB1) 5] >> ;

Comment: See my answer, edited above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think this issue is gs did not found the chinese font my used.

That would seem to be highly unlikey. If Ghostscript can't find a font, then it will use a substitute to replace the missing font. Depending on a number of factors it will choose what it think is a 'suitable' font. I won't claim its impossible to defeat this, and get an error instead, but it seems unlikely to me.

> this font path is /usr/share/fonts/truetype/yozo/yzdwkj6.ttf, I have try to add this
>   font to /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Init/cidfmap,

OK so that's not a **Font**, its a **CIDFont**, there are significant differences.

> but the PDF file have
>   below line: /BaseFont /Yozo Kai. how can I do for this description information is a > two-word font?

I assume you mean for a 2 byte encoding. The answer is that you should only have to suuply a CIDFont named "Yozo Kai". However.... Using a space in a font name is a really bad idea, because spaces are delimiters in PostScript and PDF, so the line you've posted above is technically invalid.

Instead of creating a dictionary containing a key `/BaseFont` and the value `/Yozo Kai` the PDF file actually creates a dictionary with a key `/BaseFont` and the value `/Yozo`, with a spare string `Kai` left lying around. This means the dictionary does not have an even number of entries, and so is illegal. Exactly what happens under these circumstances is not defined.

Note, I'm taking what you say verbatim, since I haven#'t got the PDF file to look at, but this error message:

> **** Error: File has an unbalanced >> (close dictionary).
>               Output may be incorrect.

suggests I am correct, the number of entries isn't even so Ghostscript has eaten the closing `>>` and then complains because it can't find a closing dictionary mark.

> If I use below script to describe this font, printing driver will
>   output filter failed log.
>
> /Yozo Kai << /FileType /TrueType /Path pssystemparams
>   /GenericResourceDir get (/usr/share/fonts/truetype/yozo/yzdwkj6.ttf)
>   concatstrings /CSI [(GB1) 5] >> ;

Same reason, you can't make a name which contains a space like that, because spaces are delimiters. In PostScript (which is how cidfmap is defined) you can do this:

```
(Yozo Kai) cvn <</FileType...... ...../CSI [(GB1) 5] >> ;
```

Note that I'm still pretty doubtful about the path you have in there, because that is concatenating the Ghostscript Generic Resource Directory with 'usr/share/...' which seems unlikely to be correct to me. I suspect you simply want `/Path (/usr/share/fonts/truetype/yozo/yzdwkj6.ttf)`.

But the real problem is (or appears to be) that your PDF file is broken. The correct way to embed a font with a space in the name would be:

```
/BaseFont /Yozo#20Kai
```

That is, you replace the unusable character (in this case space) with an escape character '#' and then follow it with the byte describing the ASCII character you want to use and then carry on. For fonts with multibyte encoding names you have to use escape codes for all the 'unprintable' character codes.

Since your PDF file doesn't follow the rules it is fundamentally broken, you should contact the creators of the software which was used to make the PDF file and inform them that they have a bug. The only way to correct this is going to be to remake the PDF file.

Comment: thanks, may I ask one more questions？
Below is a normal PDF file, what's the mean of the QNAAAA? I can not found this string under /usr/share/ in my system.
13 0 obj
<< /Type /FontDescriptor
/FontName /QNAAAA+NotoSansCJKjp-Regular
/Flags 4
/FontBBox [-1002 -1048 2928 1808 ]
/ItalicAngle 0
/Ascent 1160
/Descent -320
/CapHeight 1160
/StemV 50
/FontFile2 14 0 R
>> endobj

Comment: The string XXXXXX+ as part of a filename is the canonical means for indicating that an embedded font is a subset; that is it does not contain all the glyph descriptions from the original font. The subset portion should be unique, and means that the total font name (subset prefix + font name) can be used to differentiate between different subsets of the same font. Subset fonts are usually encoded with a custom encoding (or CMap) so you cannot usually substitute another font (not even the original full font). This is covered in section 5.5.3 of the PDF reference.